# android:How to prevent the size of image button or image view being scaled in listView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

There are some rows in listView and each rows has the same format :
From left to Right
ImageView TextViews ImageButton.
i am using relative layout to fix the position of the components but the size of the ImageButton is scaled and only imageButton displayed on each rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_resultItem_Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bBasicDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imgBook">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/authors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/authors" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publisher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/publisher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/status" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/temp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bBasicDesc"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any wrong in my xml coding?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing `wrap_content` it takes the size of the image that you set as `src`. That is why its getting scaled and bigger..

To resolve this, instead of using `wrap_content` you should think about what is the right height that you want for the `listView` item, and then for both `ImageView` and `ImageButton` set something like:

```
android:layout_width="50dp"  // sample value of 50dp
android:layout_height="50dp" // sample value of 50dp
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" // or android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom height and width of the image you are inputting into your layout. This way no matter what the image will stay that size and not try to stretch or shrink.

You can do this within your activity's .xml file using:

```
android:layout_width="yourwidthhere.dp"  
android:layout_height="yourheighthere.dp"
```